# Solve the minimization problem using subdifferentials on a non-differentiable continuous function subject to two constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, differential, constraints

This is a desmos plot of the problem I am exploring: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0rxekqcj26

My first question is how to find the subdifferential of $f(x,y) = \max\{|x|, y + 4\}$. From my plotting, I see that it is just this function $h(x) = |x + 2| + 2$, but I don't think I can just take a subdifferential of this single variable function, which would give me something like
$$
\{-1\} \quad x < -2\\
[-1, 1] \quad x = -2\\
\{1\} \quad x > -2
$$
From here, not sure where to go.

Next, we have constraints $g_1(x,y) = (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 - 1 \leq 0$ and $g_2(x,y) = |x| + y - b \leq 0$. Of the two constraints, one of them has an arbitrary parameter $b>0$. I'm not sure how to think about a solution that depends on this $b$.

Comment: Your function is a function of two variables. Here $y$ is not a function of $x$. So, your function $h(x)$ does not mean much. The points non-differentiability are given by $x=0$ with $y+4\le |x|$ and $|x|=y+4$.

Comment: Yea I thought so too, it's a 2 var function so I probably can't just write $h(x)$. Do you mean a strict inequality here? $y + 4 < |x|$ and $y + 4 = |x|$? How do I use Lagrange multipliers after this?

Comment: No, closed is fine. Why would you think it should be open? Those are the points of non-smoothness of $f$ where you will have to compute the subdifferential. At all the other points, the function is differentiable. The multipliers are added in exactly the same way as for standard optimization.

Comment: Ok I see that the multiplier should give us some sort of 'cone'. But how do I find the candidate minimizer in this case?

Comment: You have not explained what you want to do. Do you want to solve the problem analytically or solve it numerically? Either way, the approach is the same as in the differentiable case.

Comment: I want to solve it analytically using the subdifferential method. The subdifferential of a convex function is just the gradient. I know I have the candidate for local min $x_0$ satisfying the Lagrange equation $\nabla f(x) + \lambda_1 \nabla g_2(x, y) + \lambda_2 \nabla g_2(x,y)$, but I don't know how to find the correct $x_0\in \partial f(x,y)$ that is also in $\partial \lambda_i g_i(x,y)$

Comment: Are you familiar with smooth optimization?

Comment: I'm not, could you outline an example of how that will help me find the $x_0$? I feel like the answer I can see geometrically when I plot out the problem, but it's not clear how to solve it analytically using the subdifferential method of lagrangians

Comment: So, in this case, I would recommend you to learn smooth optimization and only then look the nonsmooth case. Please check the book by Boyd and Vandenberghe for a start.